# Activar Fullscreen utilizando mouseover o onmouseover

Tags: javascript

actualmente utilizo el siguiente codigo para el Fullscreen y funciona de maravilla cuando se uliza "onclick":

```
    <p onmouseover="openFS(this) id="mysite"><h2>Fullscreen with JavaScript</h2>
<button onclick="openFS();">Open texto in Fullscreen Mode</button></p>
        <script>
var elem = document.getElementById("mysite");
function openFS() {
  if (elem.requestFullscreen) {
    elem.requestFullscreen();
  } else if (elem.mozRequestFullScreen) { /* Firefox */
    elem.mozRequestFullScreen();
  } else if (elem.webkitRequestFullscreen) { /* Chrome, Safari & Opera */
    elem.webkitRequestFullscreen();
  } else if (elem.msRequestFullscreen) { /* IE/Edge */
    elem.msRequestFullscreen();
  }
}
</script>
```

Mi problema se presenta cuando la funcion no se activa al utilizar "mouseover" ni "onmouseover="openFS(this)" s", o si hay alguna manera de usar if {mouseover} else {onclick} o algo asi, no se realmente como se podria lograr, en teoria es lo que nesecito. El codigo es js que es el mas utilizo pero si es de usar jquery pues ni modo pero que sea como ultima opcion.

Esperando pronta respuesta, y agradeciendo toda ayuda por adelantado.

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con el siguiente codigo...
Saludos

```js
 

var elem = document.getElementById("mysite");
function openFS() {
  console.log('full');
  if (elem.requestFullscreen) {
    elem.requestFullscreen();
  } else if (elem.mozRequestFullScreen) { /* Firefox */
    elem.mozRequestFullScreen();
  } else if (elem.webkitRequestFullscreen) { /* Chrome, Safari & Opera */
    elem.webkitRequestFullscreen();
  } else if (elem.msRequestFullscreen) { /* IE/Edge */
    elem.msRequestFullscreen();
  }
}
```

```html
<div onmouseover="openFS(this)" id="mysite">
<h2>Fullscreen with JavaScript</h2>
<button onclick="openFS()">Open texto in Fullscreen Mode</button>
</div>
```

Comment: y si añades una explicación para saber por que debe usar este código?

Answer (score 0):

Te imprime algún error en la consola del navegador? (Se puede abrir desde `F12` em chrome).
Tambien te digo... No has cerrado comillas para cerrar la función onmouseover
 `<p onmouseover="openFS(this)" id="mysite">`